# how to get "minitest" Notification Center alerts on macOS Catalina?

Tags: minitest, notificationcenter

How can I get a "Macos Notification Center" alert when minitests pass or fail?

I'm on macOS Catalina.

Comment: for example,.....

Answer (score 0):

A crude but obvious way on a Mac is to pass thru AppleScript:

```
s = 'display notification \"Your toast is ready.\" with title \"Done\"'
`osascript -e "#{s}"`
```

Comment: But given Catalina's security lockdown there might be other hoops to jump through; I tested that on Sierra which is a very different kettle of fish

Comment: didn't work on Catalina. The package called Heroku-cli is able to do it, so some authors find it possible I guess.

Comment: I just tested on Catalina and it works fine for me so I guess it depends where you are running this from. But you didn't reveal that.

Comment: hmm its Terminal.app

Comment: apparently its blocked by default-> https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/3653#issuecomment-539412744